# iPad vs iPadPro Constraints solution

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, constraints

I'm having some problems with constraints.
I'm working on a universal app iphone ... The various views are correct, I have no problems in this for now, I'm experiencing a severe problem with costraints when I work from iPad to iPadPro.

My problem between the two are the spaces ... I show you a picture for you to understand what my problem ..

On the left you have iPad display
A Right Visualization iPadPro

Now as you can see on ipad pro I have many spaces between the various labels and other items and can not understand how I should work on constraints to modify the spaces that are there.

When working from iphone to ipad is all very easy because you just use the Compact Compact variables or Regular Regular etc ... but between the two ipad how I can work on this?
I would like to change the spacing of ipadpro constraints. I would like to make it similar to what you see in the picture ipad

In short, it would be great if you could just shrink the window with the items he iPadPro

[image]